# How to solve "Cannot set the value of read-only property 'classpath' for object of type ..." error in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, aspectj, gradle-plugin, freefair-aspectj

I have:

```
    compileJava {
        ajc {
            enabled = true
            classpath = configurations.aspectj
            options {
                aspectpath = configurations.aspect
                compilerArgs = []
            }
        }
    }

    compileTestJava {
        ajc {
            enabled = true
            classpath = configurations.aspectj
            options {
                aspectpath = configurations.testAspect
                compilerArgs = []
            }
        }
    }
```

in my `build.gradle`, with Gradle 6.6.1, as given in the documentation [FreeFair Gradle Plugin Collection](https://docs.freefair.io/gradle-plugins/current/reference/), but this results in the following error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'leo'.
> Cannot set the value of read-only property 'classpath' for object of type io.freefair.gradle.plugins.aspectj.AjcAction.
```

How can this be resolved?

Comment: do u have a solution?